# matplotlib plot from dataframe but shift dates in x labels

Tags: pandas, datetime, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have this dataframe:

```
dates;A;B;C
2018-01-31;1;2;5
2018-02-28;1;4;3    
2018-03-31;1;5;5    
2018-04-30;1;6;3    
2018-05-31;1;6;7    
2018-06-30;1;7;3    
2018-07-31;1;9;9    
2018-08-31;1;2;3    
2018-09-30;1;2;10   
2018-10-31;1;4;3    
2018-11-30;1;7;11
2018-12-31;1;2;3
```

I read it:

```
dfr = pd.read_csv('test.dat', sep=';', header = 0, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

and then I try to plot it:

```
width = 5
dfr.index = pd.to_datetime(dfr.index)
x = date2num(dfr.index)
axs.bar(x-0.5*width,dfr.iloc[:,1], width=width)
axs.bar(x+0.5*width,dfr.iloc[:,2], width=width)
axs.xaxis_date()

months = dates.MonthLocator()

axs.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter(r'\textbf{%B}')) 
months_f = dates.DateFormatter('%B')
axs.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)

plt.setp( axs.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90)
```

here the modules imported:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as dates
```

and here the result:

[image]

I do not get why x label starts with 'Feb'.
I would like to have something like 'Jan,Feb,Mar...' as x labels in the x axis.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure whether this is still relevant for you, but the issue comes from the way you're manually setting the bar positions: if you look at the x-axis data for e.g. January, you're plotting bars at the dates corresponding to `2018-01-28` and `2018-02-02` since you essentially take `01-31` and add/subtract 2.5 days. Quick fix: use `x = x -30`.

Answer (score 0):

The heights of the bar charts you made do not correspond to the labelled month, i.e. the values for Feb are actually those of Jan. Therefore, the problem is in the way you labelled the axis rather than having an incorrect plot order.

I'm not so familiar with the packages you used, so I proposed a different way of making your plot:

```py
dfr['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(dfr['dates'])
### group by months
month_vals = dfr.groupby(dfr['dates'].map(lambda x: x.month))
month_vals = sorted(month_vals, key=lambda m: m[0])

fig, axs = plt.subplots()

spacing = 0.15
### Create the list of months and the corresponding dataframes
months, df_months = zip(*month_vals)
### In your case, each month has exactly one entry, but in case there are more, sum over all of them 
axs.bar([m-spacing for m in months], [df_m.loc[:,'B'].sum() for df_m in df_months], width=0.3)
axs.bar([m+spacing for m in months], [df_m.loc[:,'C'].sum() for df_m in df_months], width=0.3)

axs.set_xticks(months)
### 1900 and 1 are dummy values; we are just initializing a datetime instance here
axs.set_xticklabels([datetime.date(1900, m, 1).strftime('%b') for m in months])
```

Output:

[image]